# QR Code Result As An Clickable Link + Result

Tags: javascript, html

found this code on https://reeteshghimire.com.np/2021/05/27/access-camera-and-read-qr-code-using-javascript/ , basically allow to scan qr code and give its results in plain text, however I wanted that the result is a clickable link for ie [www.google.com/(qrcodescanresult)](http://www.google.com/(qrcodescanresult))

```
<script src="html5-qrcode.min.js"></script>
    <style>
  .result{
    background-color: green;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
  }
  .row{
    display:flex;
  }
    </style>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
    <div style="width:500px;" id="reader"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" style="padding:30px;">
        <h4>SCAN RESULT</h4>
        <div id="result">Result Here</div>
  </div>
    </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
    function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span class="result">'+qrCodeMessage+'</span>';
}

function onScanError(errorMessage) {
  //handle scan error
}

    var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);

    </script>
```

I tried to make the `<div id="result">Result Here</div> to <div> <a id="result" href="https://www.google.com/+qrCodeMessage+"></a> </div>` but its not working. The result became clickable but not with the right link/result.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: tried changed <div id="result">Result Here</div> to <a id="result" href="https:/google.com/+qrCodeMessage+"></a>  ...no good

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share what "not working" means

Comment: Pay a bit more attention. You are using double quote in the content you say you are trying to add, so that means you are probably still using single quotes as delimiters. In the original, the syntax was `'<span class="result">'+qrCodeMessage+'</span>'` - explicitly _ending_ the text literal first, and then using the concatenation operator `+`. But ending the text literal first is missing from your attempt.

Comment: ```<script type="text/javascript">
function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span class="result"> https://google.com/'+qrCodeMessage+' </span>';
}```   was able to add website before the search result, still need to make it clickable/link

Comment: sucess!! ```<script type="text/javascript">
function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '     <a href="https://google.com/'+qrCodeMessage+'">Scanned Link Generated</a>   ' ;
}```

Answer (score 0):

success!!

```
<script src="html5-qrcode.min.js"></script>
    <style>
  .result{
    background-color: green;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
  }
  .row{
    display:flex;
  }
    </style>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
    <div style="width:500px;" id="reader"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" style="padding:30px;">
        <h4>SCAN RESULT</h4>
        <div id="result">Result Here</div>
  </div>
    </div>


 <script type="text/javascript"> function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '     <a href="https://google.com/'+qrCodeMessage+'">Scanned Link Generated</a>   ' ; }

function onScanError(errorMessage) {
  //handle scan error
}

    var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);

    </script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?